# LINQ to SQL Association Mapping

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am working on a simple command line app to teach myself some LINQ to SQL in C#. I have a SQL Server 2008 instance and I am trying to look in MSDB for the Jobs currently setup on the SQL Server. I want to output the Job Name a dot and the Step name and the actual SQL statement to do that is the following:

```
use msdb
go

select j.name + '.' + s.step_name
from sysjobs j
join sysjobsteps s on j.job_id = s.job_id
order by j.name
go
```

I am at a loss for how to establish the relationship between SysJobs and SysJobSteps in the C# code and I keep getting the following error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid association mapping for member 
'ServerCompare.Lib.Commands.SysJob.SysJobSteps'. 
'ServerCompare.Lib.Commands.SysJob' is not an entity.
```

Please advise what is the best way to do this?

Comment: give us some linq-to-sql code!

Comment: I have posted sample code in C# of what I am trying to accomplish here: https://gist.github.com/947347

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Both tables must have a defined primary key. Use `Column(Name="whatever_id", IsPrimaryKey=true)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the answer that will solve the problem for most people.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a dbml file first, adding those two tables and then use something like this:

```
 using (var context = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                var result = from s in context.sysjobs
                             orderby s.name
                             join sjs in context.sysjobsteps on s.job_id equals sjs.job_id
                             select new {Name = s.name + "." + sjs.step_name};

            }
```

To create a dbml with system tables you need to do create a connection first, then right-click the server -> change view -> object type, you should now see all system tables. Then add the two tables.